# Angular ui-router: Where to put $promise method or howto load asynchronously?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-grid

This is my state provider of my ui-router:

```
 ...
 resolve: {
            myModelData: ['$http', function($http) {
                 return $http.get('api:port/path').then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                })
            }]
        },
 ...
```

My controller depends on myModelData, it binds it two-way-style to ng-grid:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'myModelData'...) {
$scope.myModelData = myModelData;
$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: $scope.myModelData,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            ...
        };
```

As the code stands my whole footer, header, navigation waits on ui-router to load the resource. How would I load from the source asynchronously and not block the rest of the DOM to be loaded, yet also not break my ng-grid dependence.

Comment: How are your states and views structured? I would recommend creating 3 views. <div ui-view='header'></div><div ui-view></div><div ui-view='footer'></div>.  Then make a parent state that fills in header and footer views. Make the child state fill in the unnamed view and put your resolve on the child. Of course, you'll need to ensure the user navigates to the parent state before the child, or you will end up blocking again (I'm thinking about loading the child state via a bookmark).

Comment: Resolves are designed to block the transition until they are resolved. The alternative is to not use a resolve, and simply load your data async in the controller. Manually hide/show the grid based on the promise resolving.